# Dedicated wiring to luminaire - what's the minimum gauge

Tags: wiring, light-fixture, light, gauge

I am wiring a luminaire fixture through a short dedicated 1/2" EMT conduit (a couple of feet). The maximum rating on the luminaire is 100W, although I expect to use much lower wattage. What is the minimum gauge wire I am allowed to use? Am I allowed to used something smaller than 14AWG in the conduit (say, 16AWG)?

Comment: I think you have to maintain 14 until you are actually AT the luminaire, but I'll defer to one of the usual suspects.

Answer (score 2):

You're logicking out that since the lamp can't draw more than 100W, a smaller wire size should suffice.  That is covered under the [tap rules](http://ecmweb.com/code-basics/understanding-rules-feeder-taps).

Metal conduit is required because the lamp could suffer a fault condition where it pulls too much current for its tap wiring but not enough to trip the breaker.  For instance if you had a 14AWG tap off a 125A circuit, and then had a 75A fault.

But this is all pointless if you can't find 16/18/20 AWG THHN which is actually cheaper than 14 AWG, and [you probably can't.](https://awcwire.wordpress.com/2015/10/19/tffn-wire-vs-thhn-wire/)

Not least, because NEC does not allow wiring smaller than 14 AWG on any branch circuit.  Some cities have local ordinances increasing it to 12 AWG.

*Within* equipment is a different story, e.g. the interconnections within a chandelier.